# Nested loops in jinja2 template

Tags: json, loops, ansible, nested, jinja2

I am templating JSON with jinja2 and trying to iterate through list of lists, using 4 nested loops, and it is failing with message:
"AnsibleError: template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'"
As original JSON template is a bit bigger, I miss to paste here simple JSON key:value pairs. 
Can you please support me on this. Thanx
This is path of template where main logic is:

```
{ ....
    "panels": [
      {% set frame_meter_servers= ["frame-meter10-246-44-20", "frame-meter10-246-45-92", "frame-meter10-246-46-234"] %}
      {% set frame_procstat_meter_services= ["frame-meter-clock.service", "frame-meter-web.service"] %} 
      {% set frame_cpanel_backend_config_cluster_nodes= ["10.246.45.189", "10.246.46.102", "10.246.44.163"] %}
      {% set frame_procstat_cpanel_services= ["frame-cpanel-backend"] %}
      {% set frame_services_monitoring_hosts= ["frame_cpanel_backend_config_cluster_nodes", "frame_meter_servers"] %}
      {% set frame_platform_services= ["frame_procstat_cpanel_services", "frame_procstat_meter_services"] %}
      {% set id = namespace(total=1) %}
      {% set z = namespace(total=0) %}
      {% for node in frame_services_monitoring_hosts %}
        {% set nodeloop = loop %}
        {% for service in frame_platform_services %}
          {% if nodeloop.index == loop.index %}
            {
              ...
                "x": 0,
                "y": {{ z.total }}
              },
              "id": {{ id.total }},
              "panels": [],
              ...
            },
            {% set x = namespace(total=0) %}
            {% set y = namespace(total=1) %}
            {% for hosts in node %}
            {% set x = namespace(total=0) %}
              {% for services in service %}
                {
                  ...
                    "x": {{ x.total }},
                    "y": {{ y.total }}
                  },
                  "id": {{ id.total }},
                  ...
                },
                {% set x.total = 4 + x.total %}
                {% set id.total = 1 + id.total %}
                {% endfor %}
              {% set y.total = 6 + y.total %}
            {% endfor %}
              {% set y = namespace(total=4) %}
            {% for hosts in node %}
              {% set x = namespace(total=0) %}
            {% for services in service %}
                {
                  ...
                  ],
                  "valueName": "current"
                } {% set x.total = 4 + x.total %} {% set id.total = 1 + id.total %} {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
                {% set y.total = 6 + y.total %} {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if node|length == 2 %} {% set z.total = 14 + z.total %} {% else %} {% set z.total = 20 + z.total %}{% endif %}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% set id.total = 1 + id.total %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% set id.total = 1 + id.total %}{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
  ],
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `{% if {{ nodeloop.index }} == {{ loop.index }} %}`

That is incorrect syntax; everything inside the `{%` and `%}` is conceptually Python; what you want to say is:

```
      {% if nodeloop.index == loop.index %}
```

I didn't check the rest of that wall of text, but I'm super positive that `if` was wrong, so let's start there

Comment: Thank you for your support. I have changed what you proposed, but unfortunately still same error.

Comment: Actually, it works better now. Mdaniel, you were right. I have not tested well for the first time. Thank you very much!

Comment: And just one more correction here. To work me as expected I redefine mentioned variables this way.{% set frame_services_monitoring_hosts = [frame_cpanel_backend_config_cluster_nodes,frame_meter_servers] %}
    {% set frame_platform_services = [frame_procstat_cpanel_services,frame_procstat_meter_services] %}